# Вопрос по pygame (спавн шаров, увеличение их размера, взаимодействие с ними)

Tags: python

вопросы по python(pygame).
Пытаюсь сделать игру, где в рандомном месте на экране появляются шарики, и игроку надо успеть их лопать кликом мышки, со временем увеличивается скорость спавна этих самых шариков. Так вот, у меня вопрос по поводу того, как мне лучше увеличивать размер спрайта с каждым тиком. И еще я не могу придумать логику спавна и взаимодействия с этими самыми шариками. Шарики еще должны увеличиваться до определенного размера.
Пример такой игры:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCQp1Q8ANCM (смотреть с 0:31)

```
import pygame
import random
import os
from random import randrange

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
FPS = 100


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)


# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("TouchMe!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'images')
ball_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'ball.png'))




class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = ball_img
        self.image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))
        self.size = self.image.get_size()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int(self.size[0]*0.05), int(self.size[1]*0.05)))
        #self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int(self.size[0]+0.001), int(self.size[1]+0.01)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.center = (randrange(500), randrange(500))
    def update(self):
      pass


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
ball = Ball()
all_sprites.add(ball)


running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Добавьте код в сам вопрос.

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Comment: В PayGame можно использовать спрайты как кнопки(Button). Именно в этом классе можно реализовать обработку кликов на спрайты.
В качестве примера можете покапаться в моем альфа-проекте на Гит:
https://github.com/QtekTaF/CrosswordoManiya

Comment: Спасибо, погляжу